# How do I change the color of a cell based on the color of several cells?

Tags: excel, colors

I would like to change the color of cell A4 to Black if ALL of C4-C13 is Red.

sample

[image: 1]

I have tried an if function and can't seem to get it to work.

```
if(C4:C13=ColorIndex value 3,ColorIndex value 1,0)
```

Comment: You should tag this post with `excel`.

Comment: Does this help?  https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-get-cell-color/